# EV training and leveling up

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm new to X and Y and I'm a bit confused about how EV works. Let's say I have two Gyarados, one at level 20 and the other at level 70. If I EV train them the same way so that they have the same EV spreads and suppose they have the same nature and IVs, will they have the same stats at level 100? Now suppose that the one at level 70 was previously EV trained and I just changed his spread to match the one at level 20. Would this change the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, so long as your two Gyarados have identical Natures and IV, the same EV spread will give them identical stats at L100, no matter when they changed their EV spreads. In fact, you can change your EV spread at L100 through Super Training and you will still end up with identical stats.

Comment: Beat me by 7 seconds.